# Best practice on Return type of rest web api

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a get rest api, which will return a list of objects in json format

What is best practice for return type of a rest api?

Which one should I use?  Thanks

```
public HttpResponseMessage MyGetMethod(int acctId, string userId)
or 
public HttpMyObjectResponse MyGetMethod(int acctId, string userId)
```

Comment: This is really a question to me. Can you guys point me to some doc. I am searching on stackoverflow.

Comment: Dont know how it should be, but when I was interested in that, I used HttpResponseMessage, because I want to return not only data, but HTTP status code too ( my sample https://github.com/tym32167/webapisample/blob/master/src/Sample/Controllers/SampleController.cs )

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want to return some code that is not any HttpStatusCode

Comment: Actually, you shouldnt return non-standard http codes. Generally, you should use just some of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general `HttpResponseMessage` is better because you can do things like set the status code, add additional headers, etc. in the response.

Say the `userId` that was passed in doesn't exist.  Then you could do something like

`return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "That user does not exist");`

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want to return some code that is not any HttpStatusCode, e.g.  1234, "user not exist".  The way I can think is to create another class inherting from HttpStatusCode.  Is this the right way? thanks

Comment: If you return a status that is not an HTTP Status Code, no client is going to understand what the heck is going on because you will not be adhering to the HTTP standard.  Every request needs to respond [with a W3C standard status](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).  You can return an object (serialized as JSON) as the response instead of a string if you want, and that can contain anything.